# cannot get Tails-installer on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS installed

Tags: 14.04

at https://tails.boum.org/install/debian/usb/index.en.html I smoothly reached the section of 2/6 (running Ubuntu, not Debian), point 9, where my searching for Tails-installer in Ubuntu Software Center did NOT find anything, even though I did everything according to the picture right below (sudo update-apt-xapian-index, restart Ubuntu).

Any idea what next? Thank you all!

Comment: Try first with `sudo apt-get update`, to update the list of indices of repositories.

Comment: I tried... unfortunately, still the same...

Comment: Which alternative for the Ubuntu-related instructions did you use? None of the refer to 14.04 and as far as I can tell it's not currently supported.

Comment: You may have to add an additional repository. Check online to see if Tails is in a specific apt repository; and if so, how to add it to your list of sources.

Answer (score 2):

The Tail installation instructions explicitly states that the Tails installer is available on:

```
Debian 8 (Jessie) or later in the backports repository
Ubuntu 15.10 (Wily) or later in a PPA (Personal Package Archive)
```

If you cannot install the Tails installer, you need to use GNOME Disks application instead, as instructed on the link you cite.

Answer (score 1):

As indicated on the page you linked:

*If your version of Debian, Ubuntu, or Linux Mint is not supported, you can follow the instructions for other Linux distributions instead.
But they are more complicated and require two USB sticks instead of
one.*

Those instructions are [here](https://tails.boum.org/install/linux/usb/overview/index.en.html)

Since even the alternate instructions available don't cover 14.04 explicitly I would recommend obtaining a live media of 16.04 (preferably on optical disk to avoid confusion with the intermediate and target flash drives), booting off of it and following the instructions for 16.04 or later found on the page I linked above. When the process is complete you will have tails installed on a Flash drive